# How to add directories and register XML schema to Oracle DB server hosted on Docker?

Tags: docker, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have Oracle 12c DB hosted on docker and I cannot find a way to add xml schemas to DB (using SQL Developer).

I have transferred needed directory w/ files from the local machine to Docker container, I have granted all permissions and needed user groups to the folder:

`drwxrwxrwx 2 oracle dba 4096 Dec 23 19:21 DB3`

Directory DB3 content - LEAGUES.xsd and LEAGUE.xml

SQL script:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XMLDATA AS '/DB3'; `

`BEGIN
    DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://localhost:8080/home/leagues.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename('XMLDATA', 'leagues.xsd'));
end;
/`
```

And this code gives me an error response that the file doesn't exist.

ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
No such file or directory

Pretty sure that I am doing something wrong but since this pretty much is the first time I have been working with DB servers I cannot find a way to fix this issue.

Would appreciate some hints or directions where to look for them to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you transferred your directory to the docker host. For the Oracle process to access it, it must be "transferred" to inside the docker container.

Three ways to do this :

- get a shell to inside your docker container (`docker exec -it <containerid> /bin/sh`), then fetch the directory
  from there using ssh or another file-copying tool (which you may have
  to install first, inside the container). Not very secure, I wouldn't
  recommend doing this if you're running on anything else than your
  local machine for development purposes.
- rebuild your docker image, adding your DB3 folder to it along the way. You can do this even if you are using an upstream image which
  you havent built yourself : `echo "FROM base/oracle:12c \n COPY /DB3 /DB3" | docker build -t custom/oracle:12c -`
- mount your /DB3 folder on the host as a volume into the container : `docker run -v /DB3:/DB3 <other options and arguments>` (or the equivalent in your descriptor files if you are running on Openshift/Rancher/...)

Also make sure that the file names have a matching case between your script and the filesystem.

Comment: Well, it should, I'm using these techniques daily for similar needs. Can you give me more information about your context and the steps you are taking ? Base image name, execution environment, etc... so that I can help you ?

Comment: Actually yes, it does work! Tried spinning up container one more time and looks like it did the trick.
Thanks a lot!